# Trying to disprove a statement - some partial working included

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, computer-science

I am trying to find a counter example to show that the statement below is false, but I am having difficulty in trying to find a reasonable argument. Here is the statement:

$n^2-12n + 35 \geq 0$ for every positive integer $n$.

This is all I have thus far upon trying to show that the statement is false -

Let $n = 6$.

Then, we have the following:

$(6)^2 - 12(6) + 35 = -1$.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction or possibly give me some hints to further disprove this statement?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Didn't you already find the counterexample?

Comment: You've already shown that the statement is false.

Comment: Sidenote: Since $n^2-12n+35 = (n-6)^2-1$, you can see that $n = 6$ is the only counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

To prove that the statement:

$$\forall n\in\Bbb N,\quad n^2-12n+35\ge0$$
isn't true it suffices to show that its negation:
$$\exists n_0\in\Bbb N,\quad n_0^2-12n_0+35<0$$
 is true and your choice $n_0=6$ does the job.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $\bf f(n)= n^2-12n + 35$ is a quadratic equation in $\bf n$,
Discriminant of which is $\bf D=\sqrt{12^2-4.35}=2$ which is positive and thus there must exist two distinct roots of it which are $\bf 5$ and $\bf 7$ [remember $\alpha,\beta=\{12\pm\sqrt{4}\}/2$ from quadratic formula];Since it is a parabola facing upwards it must have negative values in between $\bf 5$ and $\bf 7$ which includes your $\bf 6$.